# php - adding video to php

Tags: php, windows, flash, ffmpeg

how can i add a **ffplay.exe (ffmpeg)** video to php script. can i use `exec()` to access the ffplay.

Comment: Do you want the video on a webpage, or do you want to run PHP from the command line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php- executing a exe from php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116044/php-executing-a-exe-from-php)

Answer (score 2):

You can't play video with PHP. You need to embed it somehow. Usually this is done with flash. Try [jwplayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do video processing in PHP you probably could do something similar.

If you want to have a PHP page display a video to a user then you are going down the wrong track. You have to use either Flash, Silverlight or HTML 5, and PHP will just print out the relevant syntax.

Answer (score 0):

you can use exec() to execute ffplay.exe and there are few other commands for executing external programs in PHP Refer: http://www.chipmunkninja.com/Program-Execution-in-PHP:-exec-m@