# php- executing a exe from php

Tags: php, ffmpeg

how can we  execute a ffplay.exe file from php in windows.there is any way place help me out with some codes.thanks in advance.

Comment: http://au2.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [php - adding video to php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115893/php-adding-video-to-php)

Answer (score 2):

```
 `ffplay.exe ...` // Using backticks
 exec('ffplay.exe ...') // Using exec
 shell_exec('ffplay.exe ...') // Using shell_exec
 system('ffplay.exe ...') // Using system
```

There are minor variations on what each of these do, so check out the reference

Reference

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php